# How to pass containers ip address to another container?

Tags: mysql, docker, networking, phpmyadmin

I am correctly trying to pass a container ip address to another

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
 app-phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
   depends_on:
      - app-mysql
   ports:
      - '80'
   container_name: app-phpmyadmin
   environment:
      PMA_HOST: app-mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306

  app-mysql:
   image: mysql:8
   container_name: app-mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: app-phpmyadmin <<<< doesnt work see below why
   ports:
      - 3306
```

When passing app-phpmyadmin instead of passing the ip it actually writes "app-phpmyadmin" as a string. On selecting use, host from mysql.user the hostname is "app-phpmyadmin" instead of the ip.

Is there a way I can do this in the docker-compose file or would i have to come up with a bash script that does it?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need an IP address here?  (Usually using the other container’s `docker-compose.yml` service name as a host name would be correct.)

Comment: phpmyadmin are unable to access the mysql. This is because im not passing the ip address instead the container as a string. I fix this by having the root host ```%```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can have try to use static network address

```sh
version: '3.4'
services:
  app-phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     depends_on:
        - app-mysql
     ports:
        - '81'
     container_name: app-phpmyadmin
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: app-mysql
       PMA_PORT: 3306
    networks:
      app-net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  app-mysql:
    container_name: app-mysql
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 10.5.0.5
    ports:
      - 3306
    networks:
      app-net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
version: '3'
services:
 app-phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
   depends_on:
      - app-mysql
   ports:
     - '8081:80'
   container_name: app-phpmyadmin #name expose at list: docker ps
   hostname: app-phpmyadmin #hostname in network docker
   environment:
      PMA_HOST: app-mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: "root"
      PMA_PASSWORD: "root"

 app-mysql:
   image: mysql:5.7 #downgrade beacause mysql 8 generate error with phpmyadmin. error: caching_sha2_password
   container_name: app-mysql #name expose at list: docker ps
   hostname: app-mysql #hostname in network docker
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
   ports:
      - 3306
```

Comment: Setting `hostname:` has absolutely no effect on this setup; you can delete all of the `container_name:` and `hostname:` lines and the two containers will still be reachable by their service names, `app-phpmyadmin` and `app-mysql` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answe. but i got this error 

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I have fix the issue though instead of using ```MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: app-phpmyadmin``` I used ```MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %``` that fixed the problem i was having trying to connect to mysql through phpmyadmin :)

Comment: Is not necessary MYSQL_ROOT_HOST:%    by default is it. Well

Comment: @DavidMaze, i try show difference between the hostname and container name in the setup